# Fibonacci function with big number (i.e. 1000 digits) in C

Tags: c, bignum

EDIT: 
I replace:
    carry = (x-(x%10))%10;
by:
    carry = x/10;

And I add at the end of the while loop in addition():
    if(carry) f3[i] = carry;

### Thanks to FalconUSA & M_Oehm ! :)

I'm working on problem 25 of Project Euler (beware spoilers), and while the fibonacci function isn't really a problem I've difficulties to implement a way to store huge number (like there a 1000 digits).

So i've tried (as i learnt on the web) to deal with it with array, but the program is running indefinitely.
My problem is probably in addition() or length().

Any ideas about it ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int length(int *nbr) // number of digits of my number
{
    int len = 0, c = 0;

    while(nbr[c] >= 0) {
        len++;
        c++;
    }
    return len;
}

int addition(int *f1, int *f2, int *f3, int siz) // add f1+f2 and store it in f3
{
    int carry =0, i =0;
    int x;

    memset ( f3, -1, siz*sizeof(int));

    while ( (f1[i] >= 0) || (f2[i] >= 0) ) {
        if(f1[i]<0) {
            x = f2[i] + carry;
        }
        else if(f2[i]<0) {
            x = f1[i] + carry;
        }
        else {
            x = f1[i] + f2[i] + carry;
        }
        f3[i] = x%10;
        carry = (x-(x%10))%10;
        i++;
    }

    return 0;
}

int copy_arr(int *dest, int *or, int siz) //copy array "or" into "dest"
{
    int c = 0;
    memset( dest, -1, siz*sizeof(int));

    while( c < siz ) {
        dest[c] = or[c];
        c++;
    }

    return 0;
}

int fibo(int siz) //fibonacci function
{
    int f1[siz],f2[siz],f3[siz];
    memset( f1, -1, siz*sizeof(int));
    memset( f2, -1, siz*sizeof(int));
    memset( f3, -1, siz*sizeof(int));

    int n = 2;

    f1[0] = f2[0] = 1;


    while (length(f1) <= siz) {
        n++;
        addition( f1, f2, f3, siz);
        copy_arr( f2, f1, siz);
        copy_arr( f1, f3, siz);
    }

    printf("%d\n", n);

    return 0;
}


int main() // siz's value is the number of digits I desire for my fibonacci number
{
    int siz=1000;

    fibo(siz);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: For this condition `while ( (f1[i] >= 0) || (f2[i] >= 0) ) {` to terminate, **both**   parts must be < 0 at the same time. Are you sure that will always happen, or can there be different number of digits in the two arrays?

Comment: F6 = 8; and F7= 13. So i guess yes, there can be a different number of digits.

Comment: HINT: You don't need to write a program to find the answer to this.

Comment: Please remove "Solved" from your title and question. You can post the answer on its own, and even accept it. That is the proper indication  for others with a similar question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, seems like your problem is in this line:

```
carry = (x - x%10) % 10;
```

it should be just

```
carry = x - x%10;
```

or

```
carry = x / 10;
```

which is equivalend in this case.

**UPDATE:** also, in line

```
 while ( (f1[i] >= 0) || (f2[i] >= 0) ) {
```

if the size of `f1` is `siz` and the size of `f2` is also `siz`, then you'll reach the element `f1[siz]`, or even further, which is **out of range**. So, you should declaring

```
int f1[siz+1], f2[siz+1], f3[siz+1]
```

and you should setting `siz+1` edges everywhere:

```
memset( fi, -1, (siz+1)*sizeof(int)); // where 1 <= i <= 3
```

**PS:** if you only want to calculate that fibonacci number without integrating into some program that requires fast calculation, it's better to use `Python` or `Java`, because these languages have built-in long numbers support and their syntax are very easy and similar to `C++`. And, as ghostmansd mentioned above, it's better to use [GMP library](https://gmplib.org/) if you're going to use C/C++ anyways.

Comment: You were right about the carry part, but "siz+1" doesn't make it work. My program work perfectly with just "siz". Thank's :)

Comment: I think it just happens to work. You calculate until the length is greater than `siz`. When this happens, you check digits beyond the size, which is undefined behaviour. What happens is that you just calculate a length that is inaccurate, but greater than `siz`, which satisfies your condition. You could print the length in each iteration to check. (Of course, a number with 1000 + 1 digits can hold only digits of up to length 1000 and the condition `length(f1) <= 1000` will always be true, so you need to fix more than just the dimensions.)

Answer (score 3):

You could use GMP multiple precision library: https://gmplib.org. You may also want to check Fibonacci section: https://gmplib.org/manual/Fibonacci-Numbers-Algorithm.html.

**UPDATE** You may also want to check this post, which demonstrates how to implement fast Fibonacci from scratch: https://www.anfractuosity.com/2012/10/24/fib-calculation-with-gmp.

Pros of using GMP are that you will have a really fast and elaborated algorithms, written by people who know what they do. GMP is extremely fast (it is partially written in assembler and makes a deep use of various algorithms), mature and stable library. Whenever you need to work with big numbers, it's always a good idea to use GMP.

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation, i'll look on it, but for my first time with BigNum, i wanted to deal by myself to understand how does it work.

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems with your code.

Your numbers are terminated by a digit with the sentinel value −1. You need space for that extra digit, much like you need space for the null terminator in C strings. You should dimension your arrays to `siz + 1` and initialise all values including the dummy value.

When you add two numbers, you never consider the last carry. That means that your numbers never get longer. Add this after the main lop in `addition`:

```
if (carry) f3[i] = carry;
```

Your method to determine the carry isn't correct, either. The carry are the excess digits to the left:

```
carry = x / 10;
```

Comment: You were right about the carry part, but "siz+1" not. It works well with my original "siz". Thank's :)